# Can I use a php include in email header?

Tags: php, email

Trying to make this

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: $sales_rep_name <$sales_rep>' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

work with this

```
//SET UP INFORMATION GOES HERE
############################################################################
$sales_rep_name="Tommy";
$sales_rep="email@yoursite.com";
```

but it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: The string "not working" is not a built-in error message in PHP.

Comment: "not working" is a useless diagnostic. Our response could just as well be "well, maybe you're not paying the string enough".

Comment: OP: see http://emclstcd.tk for further explanation (others as well).

Answer (score 4):

You need double quotes to get variables to be interpolated within strings:

```
$headers .= "From: $sales_rep_name <$sales_rep>" . "\r\n";
            ^                                  ^
```